# How to add authors to a chapter title

Tags: sectioning, chapters, thesis

I am writing my thesis using `book` as the document class. Just below every chapter title, I would like to add in small letters - a reference to the published paper of the chapter.

Something like

```
**Using Lineage for Sub-image Data Processing** %% chapter title
 *Published as Author 1, Author 2, in XXX Journal , 2011*
```

Kindly guide me on how to create such an environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\thesischapter}{o m m}{%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}
     {\chapter[#2]{#2\origtitle{#3}}}
     {\chapter[#1]{#2\origtitle{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand\origtitle[1]{\\
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\normalsize\vspace*{2\baselineskip}#1}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\thesischapter{Using Lineage for Sub-image Data Processing}
  {Published as Author 1, Author 2, in XXX Journal , 2011}
Ciao
\chapter{A title}

Ciao
\end{document}
```