# How to add additional information to chapters and their entry in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I would like to change chapter layout/heading to contain more information. I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36637/how-to-add-authors-to-a-chapter-title) where a subtitle is added that contains information about original authors. However, I would like to include speaker (basically similar to author), event (optional) and date for each chapter so that it would look like this:

[image]

Also, I would like to include the additional information in the table of contents so that it approximately looks like this:

[image]

I also found [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/table-of-contents-with-additional-description-of-entries) that achieves additional information in the ToC but I would like to automate the entries by already specifying the text when defining the chapter.

I am a latex beginner and do not really understand the code. However, I tried to modify the above mentioned code to add not only one field with additional information but three. This unfortunately works only partly as I would have expected. Below follows my working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{}
    {\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \talk { m m o m }{
\IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\chapter[#1\\\textit{#2, #4}]{#1\beneathtitle{#2}[]{#4}}}
    {\chapter[#1\\\textit{#2, #3, #4}]{#1\beneathtitle{#2}[#3]{#4}}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \beneathtitle { m O{} m }{ \\
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\Large\textit{#1}

    \Large#2

     \Large#3}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\talk{The puzzling evolution of giant DNA viruses}{Matthias Fischer}[SFB Seminar Series]{21.10.1988}

In the viral world, size is usually defined by genome and particle size  […]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at what the `memoir` class does with its `\chapterprecistoc` command and supporting macros.

Comment: This might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60738/write-contents-of-an-environment-to-document-and-toc